# Replacement for batch files needed that employs pascal as a source language

Tags: batch-file, pascal, wsh, pascalscript

Having just completed a fairly large batch script, I have reached my limit as far as spending most of my time implementing arcane work-arounds for the inadequacies of the language.

It's time to look for something better.  Windows Scripting Host looks OK, and I can live with JScript but Pascal is my preferred lingo.

Is there a free, actively worked on, scripting tool that uses Pascal as a source language?  Something that once installed, allows me to type the name of a script file, just like batch files.  I don't want to add scripting to an application, just execute scripts from a DOS prompt.

***UPDATE***

Hmmm.  I'm having trouble seeing how the answers so far would satisfy my needs.  Maybe I missed a crucial episode.  All I want is to be able to create a file say `MyFirstScript.<whatever>`:

```
writeln ('Hello world') ;
Exec ('compiler.exe MyProg') ;
if (ErrorLevel <> 0) then
    begin
    writeln ('Oops!') ;
    end 
else
    begin
    CopyFile ('MyProg.exe', 'OutputFolder\') ;
    end ;
```

and type `MyFirstScript` at a DOS prompt (or maybe `runscript MyFirstScript`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this: http://www.be-precision.com/products/pdscript/.  Pretty much exactly what I wanted.  It's based on RemObjects Pascal Script Engine.  There is a command line compile-and-execute tool and an IDE with code completion.  After setting up an association in the registry between the CL tool and .dpas files, I was able to create a HelloWorld.dpas file and run it by typing the filename in a DOS prompt.

Brilliant.  And free.

Answer (score 1):

Not really full fledged scripting solution, but [InstantFPC](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/InstantFPC) makes it look like so. Another way would be to use [PascalScript](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx), but since it's intended to be used as application extension, you have to code a little. The code is very trivial though, you can find a working barebone [here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Pascal_Script_Examples). Just adjust the units / routines that you need.

Comment: Instantfpc and an unit with some easy tprocess wrappers goes a long way indeed. It's not in released versions yet though.

Comment: RossMcm: the mentioned instantfpc would work fine on linux etc. Maybe works a bit on Windows too. But programs must be fully functional FPC programs, so including uses and begin..end

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Script Host allows you to install [additional language engines](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/WSH-in-Other-Languages/) ([more here](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/More-Alternative-Languages-for-WSH/)) including [OpScript](http://opascalscript.sourceforge.net/) which is an Object Pascal engine.  This will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Nilpo.  That's the sort of thing I am looking for, though a quick look at it suggests there is much yet to be implemented (_case_ and _with_ for example).

Comment: Just to save anybody wasting their time, I checked again, and as of the end of 2018, it appears no more work has been done on OpScript.